# I am trying to update a value to a path using transform. Need inputs

Tags: xslt, transform

### Can someone please help why this is not updating the value of attribute MaxrequestLength to 15000

```
**Source xml**
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="360" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="100" />  
  </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

---

Transform used is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy >
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web/httpRuntime/@MaxRequestLength">
<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">15000</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

```
**Output**
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360"
                   maxRequestLength="100"
                   requestValidationMode="2.0"
                   targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML is case-sensitive. `maxRequestLength` is not the same thing as `MaxRequestLength`.

Comment: Thank you, I agree and that was a typo, in my original code there is a bigger file with the correct input and case letters but it did not work. Will check the transform on that.